# Three term recurrence relation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I was reading series solutions of ordinary differential equations in a book, and there was a three term recurrence relation. is there some general/easy way to solve them?

Eg. $(n+2)a_{n+2} -2na_{n+1}+(n-2)a_n=0$

PS- Although the author mentions two solutions to it, however, I wanted to know is there any other easier way that I can visualise it and solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general method (that i am aware of) , unless the coefficients in your linear recurrence relations are constant (which is not the case in your example).

Concerning your specific example, since $2n=(n+2)+(n-2)$, it rewrites $(n+2)b_{n+1}=(n-2)b_n$, where $b_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$. You can easily find $b_n$ from the former relation, then find $a_n$ since $a_n-a_0=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b_k$.